# How to serve files in a multi-project solution in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload, architecture, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

I have a multi-project solution i.e. **Demo.sln**.

And it has 5 projects namely **Demo.Domain.csproj**, **Demo.Infrastructure.csproj**, **Demo.Application.csproj**, **Demo.API.csproj** and **Demo.Web.csproj**.

The Demo.Web.csproj is a ASP.NET Core RazorPages project.

My folder structure is as follows:

```
  - Demo
     - src
       - Demo.Domain
       - Demo.Infrastructure
       - Demo.Application
       - Demo.API
         - ...
         - wwwroot
       - Demo.Web
         - ...
         - wwwroot
```

Now my problem is: I have file upload functionality in my app. But as you can see there are two *wwwroot* folders in my solution. One is under Demo.API and other is under Demo.Web.

But I want to store and serve files from a single place for both API and Web projects as they function as the same application but in different ways (API for serving JSON and Web for serving web).

They both rely on the same Application and Infrastructure project to function.

I tried mapping both wwwroot folders to the same folder on the host machine with docker-compose when deploying. But can't do so in a development environment when doing local environment.

What I want is to allow users to upload and see/download files on my application by using both REST API (ie. mobile app) or via web.

Comment: Files don't _have_ to be served from wwwroot. You can create an additional directory (not under your web application, but in a separate directory or even disk) and serve from there.

Comment: Can you elaborate or maybe answer with details? Or maybe provide links? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution to your problem is to create a new shared project in your solution, let's call it Demo.Shared.csproj. This project should contain a single folder named "Uploads" or any other name you prefer, which will be used to store all uploaded files.

Next, you can remove the wwwroot folders from both Demo.API and Demo.Web projects, as they will no longer be needed for file uploads.

Then, you can modify your file upload code in both Demo.API and Demo.Web projects to save the uploaded files to the shared "Uploads" folder in Demo.Shared project.

For example, in your file upload code, you can use a relative path to save the file to the shared "Uploads" folder:

**var uploadsFolder = Path.Combine("..", "Demo.Shared", "Uploads");
var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, fileName);**

And similarly, when you want to serve the uploaded files, you can read them from the shared "Uploads" folder using a similar relative path:

**var uploadsFolder = Path.Combine("..", "Demo.Shared", "Uploads");
var filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, fileName);**

This way, you can store and serve files from a single place for both API and Web projects, and they will function as the same application but in different ways.

Note that you may need to set the proper permissions on the shared "Uploads" folder to ensure that both Demo.API and Demo.Web projects have write access to it for file uploads, and read access for serving files.